# How to create Resource only Bundle for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, resources, nsbundle

We are experimenting with delivering our nibs in language specific bundles.  For a couple of different reasons this would help us out.

My questions are around setting up a resource only bundle.

1. When I add a new bundle in xcode through the “New Project - Framework & Library - Bundle” menu xcode will add a new xcodeproj file.  Is this correct?  I thought a bundle was just a directory with a .bundle extension.
2. If I want to only have nib files in my bundle do I still need an executable file and a info.plist file?

So far I have manually created a bundle directory and added nib files. I and can access it with

```
NSBundle bundleWithPath
```

Not sure if it's loaded correctly, but the bundleWithPath method does not return nil.

But when I try to open a nib file from the bundle I get the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInco nsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in
>   bundle: 'NSBundle 
>   (not yet loaded)' with name 'Nib''

And I have added the bundle to "Copy Bundle Resources".

Thanks for any info.  I'm sure I'm making this harder than it should be.

EDIT: I went back and for a test added the line below to look for the xib instead of the nib. It works for xib but not for nib.  I think this means that that the xib maybe is not getting compiled.

[languageBundle pathForResource:@"TestNib" ofType:@"xib"];

Answer (score 0):

1. No, this is not correct. You should add a new target to your current project instead of creating a new project.
2. You don't need an executable, but you will probably need an Info.plist for it to be a proper bundle (it might not be strictly necessary, but it won't hurt to have one).

Now, is there a reason you're putting your nib files in a bundle instead of in .lproj directories? Also, you'll need to show some of your actual code before we can offer further help.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I guess I don't totally understand how targets and bundles work. I'll probably do a little more research and hopefully come back with a more educated response. Thanks again.